# How to highlight multiple selection in react using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to make multiple selection and highlight them. So suppose if I am displaying 5 buttons and if user clicks on a button it will be higlighted and if the user clicks on it again then it will become normal.

I am using redux store the state of my button. These button are getting created dynamically based on how many they are.

**Redcuer**

```
 CurrentReducer(state = {court:{}}, action){
    switch (action.type){
    case 'COURT_SELECTED':{
          return {...state,
            court: action.payload
          }
        }}
```

Dispatcing action on onClick

```
this.props.dispatch(actions.selected({type:'COURT_S', payload: id}))
```

I had thought of storing id's in court by making it as an array or storing id with true or false in an object. 
can  anyone give me a simple working solution which is super easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**reduser**

```
const selectedCourts = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'COURT_TOGGLE': {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.id]: !state[action.id]
      };
    }
  }
  return state;
};
```

**action**

```
dispatch({type: 'COURT_TOGGLE', id});
```

So you'll have piece of state like this:

```
selectedCourts: {
    1: true,
    2: false,
    3: false,
    ...
  }
```

I recommend you to use [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) to split your reducer into smaller parts so each subreducer would handle a simple part of your state like an array or one level object or boolean variable.

**CurrentReducer.js**

```
export default combineReducers({
  selectedCourts,
  ...
});
```